# AngularJS currency filter: can I remove the .00 if there are no cents in the amount?

Tags: angularjs

I am following this: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:currency
When I type 1234.56 in the field then the output should be $1,234.56. But if I type in the input 1234 then the output is $1,234.00. I don't want the decimal and the zeros to appear.
How can this be done?

Comment: You can use an advanced currency filter: https://github.com/Zmetser/angular-currency-filter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing AngularJS currency filter decimal/cents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782439/removing-angularjs-currency-filter-decimal-cents)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add a new filter:

```js
'use strict';

angular
    .module('myApp')
    .filter('myCurrency', ['$filter', function($filter) {
        return function(input) {
            input = parseFloat(input);
            input = input.toFixed(input % 1 === 0 ? 0 : 2);
            return '$' + input.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');
        };
    }]);
```

In your view:

```html
<span>{{ '100' | myCurrency }}</span> <!-- Result: $100 -->
<span>{{ '100.05' | myCurrency }}</span> <!-- Result: $100.05 -->
<span>{{ '1000' | myCurrency }}</span> <!-- Result: $1,000 -->
<span>{{ '1000.05' | myCurrency }}</span> <!-- Result: $1,000.05 -->
```

Comment: instead of returning the $ symbol.. How can i return £ ??

Comment: @OamPsy, just clean up and delete your commetns, plz

Answer (score 7):

I prefer this answer as it keeps the commas to separate thousands:

[Removing AngularJS currency filter decimal/cents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782439/removing-angularjs-currency-filter-decimal-cents)

Comment: IMPORTANTLY... the answer linked here shows that this feature is now included in AngularJs, so you don't have to write any custom code.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question specifically asks to show cents unless the cents are ".00".

Comment: This doesn't answer the question like Ryan mentioned.

Answer (score 5):

If you want something quick and *dirty*, you can set the second parameter to the filter as such in order to trigger two decimal places when there are, in fact, cents to be shown:

```
{{amount | currency:undefined:2*(amount % 1 !== 0)}}
```

Quick caveat is that this only works roughly up to 10^14 since a loss of floating point precision will cause `amount % 1` to return `0`.

An alternative syntax, which works pretty much identically but is a little less understandable is `2*!!(amount % 1)`