# AngularJS .00 currency filter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-filters

I have used the .00 currency filter from: [AngularJS currency filter: can I remove the .00 if there are no cents in the amount?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17665487/angularjs-currency-filter-can-i-remove-the-00-if-there-are-no-cents-in-the-amo)

However, how can i adapt the filter to split the value by comma's?

For example,

Instead of £456789
It should show: £456,789

Here's a plunker i made: http://plnkr.co/edit/uDFWkPAmc7PrgDwHPDho?p=preview

Filter:

```
app.filter('myCurrency', ['$filter', function ($filter) {


return function(input) {
    input = parseFloat(input);
    if(input % 1 === 0) {
      input = input.toFixed(0);
    }
    return '£' + input;
  };
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you can chain filters, you could use something like the `_.str` trim filter:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/plantface/wap36ygv/)

```html
<p>My value with currency trimming filter: {{ myValue | currency:'&pound;' | _.str: 'trim':['.00'] }}</p>
```

result:

```
// My value with currency trimming filter: £242,737
```

In case you plan to support currencies as represented in different countries and so in case there's a comma ',' instead of a dot due to currency's l18n capability, you could consider a final version that includes both:

```
<p>My value with currency trimming filter: {{ myValue | currency:'&pound;' | _.str: 'trim':['.00'] | _.str: 'trim':[',00'] }}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing it:

```
app.filter('myCurrency', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
  return function(input) {
    input = parseFloat(input);
    if(input % 1 === 0) {
      input = input.toFixed(0);
    }

    return '£' + (''+input).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+($|\.))/g, "$1,");
  };
}]);
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GIzLxNXQagkgJcCR8nF8?p=preview)

### Edit

Updated filter to use a regex instead.

Comment: Thanks, but see what happens when you change myValue to 10000... Result with filter is £10,0

Comment: This circumvents the i18n power of Angular's currency filter. And quite convoluted solution.

Comment: @Plantface, First line of my post: "Here is one way of doing it". There are certainly many other ways of doing it... this is one :)