# How to customize the currency filter to display the currency symbol '€' or any other in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The default currency symbol in the `currency filter` in angularJS is `$`. how can I change that to '€' or any other ? I found some lengthy codes in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782439/removing-angularjs-currency-filter-decimal-cents).
But is there any smooth way to do it ?

```
<div ng-app=""  >

    <p>Total = {{ (10 * 13) | currency }}</p>

</div>
```

result is `Total = $130.00`
how to make it `Total = €130.00` or `Total = USD130.00`   ?

Answer (score 3):

1.Try this `{{price | currency:"€"}}` , It will solve your problem http://jsfiddle.net/TheSharpieOne/N7YuP/

2.And To make in more generalized format, it would be better if you can write custom filter for currency formats.

So that it can support any of the currency formats.

[Example](http://blog.cloudcity.io/2013/05/15/angular-js-accounting-js-and-currency/)

Answer (score 2):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency), you can specify a custom currency identifier

`{{amount | currency:"€"}}`

Angular also provides [handling for i18n/l10n](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n)

Answer (score 1):

You can supply a currency symbol to the filter:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app=""  >

    <p>Total = {{ (10 * 13) | currency : '€' }}</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is provide a symbol parameter to the currency filter. The Angular docs provides the following syntax:

```
{{ currency_expression | currency : symbol : fractionSize}}
```

The correct symbol can be found by searching on the internet. But since you asked for Euro, here are a few variations:

```
<div ng-app=""  >

    <p>Total = {{ (10 * 13) | currency:"&euro;" }}</p>

</div>
```

OR

```
<div ng-app=""  >

    <p>Total = {{ (10 * 13) | currency:"€" }}</p>

</div>
```

**Note**: the symbol parameter must be a string

Alternatively you can even use the filter in controllers or custom filters by using the JavaScript syntax provided in the docs [Angular API:currency](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency) -

For eg: $filter('currency')(input,"€"); or $filter('currency')(input,"€");

**Note**: Do remember to inject $filter into the controller or custom filter in question.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score -1):

$filter('currency')(value, currencySymbol, fraction);

Comment: The question is looking to do this in an expression, not in JavaScript code.